# How can I append a single PDF to all PDFs in a folder?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have one standard file (call it ending.pdf) that I want added to the end of all of the PDFs in a folder. Can I automate this task? I have Acrobat Pro X. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Oh, I forgot to mention I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: What OS are you using? If it's something unixy, you can use imagemagick, namely the convert command.

Comment: @SBI imagemagick "runs on Linux, Windows, Mac Os X, iOS, Android OS, and others."

Comment: I know, but depending on what you run, installing and using it is straight forward...or not ;)

Comment: Assuming Windows as platform, you could use the PDF Toolkit PDFtk: http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/  Just loop through your existing files using a CMD command file using a "for /F" construct. Take special care for encrypted/protected/compressed files.

Comment: Oops! Forgot to mention I'm on Windows 7. So when you say 'Just loop through your existing files using  a CMD command file using a "for /F" construct', can you give me an example of that? Maybe I'm not smart enough to use SuperUser! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and install [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit).
2. Copy **Ending.pdf** to one directory (say `C:\End`) and all the other PDFs to another directory.
3. At the command prompt type **pdftk** and press Enter. If you receive an error like `'pdftk' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, you'll need to add the PDFtk installation directory [to your PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) or specify the full path to **pdftk.exe** in the command below.

   Alternatively, since the app is pretty much portable and I don't see any registry keys or miscellaneous files being created/littered about the system, you can simply copy **pdftk.exe** from the installation directory to the directory where your PDFs reside.
4. At the command prompt run the following command in the directory with the PDFs you want to append **Ending.pdf** to:

   ```
    for %a in (*.pdf) do pdftk "%~a" "C:\End\Ending.pdf" cat output "%~na (Joined)%~xa"
   ```

Comment: Hey Karan, thank you so much! This works great. I just have one follow-up question. How can I make them have the same file name as the original, rather than with (Joined) at the end? I tried just removing that bit in the code, but it gives an error that the input file name matches the output file name. Perhaps having them deposited into a subfolder or something?

Comment: Yeah, you can try something like `... cat output "C:\MyPDFs\%~a"` and you should hopefully end up with new files but with their original names in `C:\MyPDFs`.